# Multivariable polynomial long division calculator

Tags: algorithms, calculator

Is there code/online calculator that divides polynomials in multiple variables? The answers are always other polynomials, but they have many variables.

Comment: This is a hard problem, because multivariate polynomials don't have a natural ordering like in the one-variable case.  You need to pick a [Grobner basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis), often with [Buchberger's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_algorithm).

Comment: @user86417 in somewhat related, but not so useful news, there is LaTeX code to do long-division of polynomials in one-variable. I used it to do some calculus II notes, very handy for partial fractions. The package is called "polynom" and it goes something like "\polylongdiv{2x^3+x^2+3x+5}{x+3}"